# Морской бой на с++. Отображение полей в консольном приложении

Tags: c++, консоль, borland-c++

Написала простенькое консольное приложение морской бой, но возникла проблема, когда его запускаю, приложение выглядит одним образом(первый скрин), а после того как совершается первый ход внешний вид меняется (второй скрин) и всё встаёт не на свои места, в чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот некоторые куски кода:

```c
void PrintArray(int m1[n][n], int nomPol) {
    if (nomPol == nomGamer - 1)
        SetColor(Red, LIGHTRED);  //если номер поля совпадает с номером игрока, то линейку поля по Х выделяем другим цветом
    else
        SetColor(Red, LightRed);
    GotoXY(nomPol * lvGrPol, verhGrPol);
    cout << "   " << 1 << "  " << 2 << "  " << 3 << "  " << 4 << "  " << 5;
    cout << "  " << 6 << "  " << 7 << "  " << 8 << "  " << 9 << "  " << 10 << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (nomPol == nomGamer - 1)
            SetColor(Red, LightRed);  //тоже самое для Y
        else
            SetColor(Red, LightRed);
        GotoXY(nomPol * lvGrPol, verhGrPol + 2 * i + 1);

        if (i == 9)
            cout << i + 1;
        else
            cout << " " << i + 1;

        GotoXY(nomPol * lvGrPol, verhGrPol + 2 * i + 2);
        cout << "  ";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                SetColor(White, DarkGray);
            else
                SetColor(White, LightGray);

            switch (m1[i][j])
            {
            case 0:     //пустая клетка
                GotoXY(nomPol * lvGrPol + 3 * j + 2, verhGrPol + 2 * i + 1);
                cout << "   ";
                GotoXY(nomPol * lvGrPol + 3 * j + 2, verhGrPol + 2 * i + 2);
                cout << "   ";
                break;

            case 9:     //клетка мимо
                SetColor(Black, Red);
                GotoXY(nomPol * lvGrPol + 3 * j + 2, verhGrPol + 2 * i + 1);
                cout << "   ";
                GotoXY(nomPol * lvGrPol + 3 * j + 2, verhGrPol + 2 * i + 2);
                cout << "   ";
                break;

            case 5:     //клетка попадание
                SetColor(Black, Green);
                GotoXY(nomPol * lvGrPol + 3 * j + 2, verhGrPol + 2 * i + 1);
                cout << "   ";
                GotoXY(nomPol * lvGrPol + 3 * j + 2, verhGrPol + 2 * i + 2);
                cout << "   ";
                break;

            default:
                GotoXY(nomPol * lvGrPol + 3 * j + 2, verhGrPol + 2 * i + 1);
                cout << "   ";
                GotoXY(nomPol * lvGrPol + 3 * j + 2, verhGrPol + 2 * i + 2);
                cout << "   ";
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void game(int mRab[n][n], int nomGamer) {
    statusGamer = 1;
    system("cls");
    PrintArray(m1Rab, 0);
    PrintArray(m2Rab, 1);

    SetColor(Black, LightGray);
    GotoXY(5, 2);
    cout << s8;
    GotoXY(45, 2);
    cout << s9;
    SetColor(White, Black);
    GotoXY(lvGrStr+2, hStr+2);
    cout << s;           //вывод состояния игры

    SetColor(Red, LightGray);
    GotoXY(20, 3);   //вывод числа попаданий игрока1
    cout << ": " << chisPop1;
    GotoXY(60, 3);   //вывод числа попаданий игрока2
    cout << ": " << chisPop2;


    SetColor(Red, LightGray);
    GotoXY(lvGrStr, hStr + 1);
    if (nomGamer == 1)
        cout << "Ходит: " << s8;
    else
        cout << "Ходит: " << s9;

    SetColor(Red, LightGray);
    GotoXY(10,1);
    cout << "Чтобы выйти из игры наберите 100 ";

    SetColor(Black, LightGray);
    GotoXY(lvGrStr, hStr + 4);
    cout << s2;
    GotoXY(lvGrStr + 4, hStr + 5);
    cin >> jKoord;

    if (jKoord != 100) //игра продолжается пока кто-либо не наберет 20 очков или не введут 100
    {
        cin >> iKoord;
        jKoord += -1;
        iKoord += -1;

        if ((iKoord >= 0) and (iKoord < 10) and (jKoord >= 0) and (jKoord < 10))
        {
            switch (mRab[iKoord][jKoord])     //если попал, то увеличивается число попаданий и показывается место попадания
            {
            case 0:     //промах
                GotoXY(lvGrStr, hStr);
                strcpy(s, s3);
                cout << s;
                mRab[iKoord][jKoord] = 9;
                statusGamer = 0;
                break;

            case 1:         //попадание
                if (nomGamer == 1) chisPop1 += 1;
                else chisPop2 += 1;
                mRab[iKoord][jKoord] = 5;
                Popadanie(mRab, 1);
                break;

            case 2:         //попадание
                if (nomGamer == 1) chisPop1 += 1;
                else chisPop2 += 1;
                mRab[iKoord][jKoord] = 5;
                Popadanie(mRab, 2);
                break;

            case 3:         //попадание
                if (nomGamer == 1) chisPop1 += 1;
                else chisPop2 += 1;
                mRab[iKoord][jKoord] = 5;
                Popadanie(mRab, 3);
                break;

            case 4:         //попадание
                if (nomGamer == 1) chisPop1 += 1;
                else chisPop2 += 1;
                mRab[iKoord][jKoord] = 5;
                Popadanie(mRab, 4);
                break;

            case 5:     //уже стреляли
                GotoXY(lvGrStr, hStr);
                strcpy(s, s6);
                cout << s;
                break;

            case 9:     //уже стреляли
                GotoXY(lvGrStr, hStr);
                strcpy(s, s6);
                cout << s;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GotoXY(lvGrStr, hStr);
            strcpy(s, s7);
            cout << s;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        tekSost = 999;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    ArrayNull(m1Rab);   //заполняем матрицу 1 нулями
    ArrayNull(m2Rab);   //заполняем матрицу 2 нулями

    SetColor(Black, LightGray);
    GotoXY(5, 1);
    cout << "Морской Бой";
    SetColor(Black, LightGray);
    GotoXY(5,2);
    cout << "Введите 1, чтобы расставить корабли автоматически, вручную - 0";
    GotoXY(10, 3);
    cin >> statusRast;

    if (statusRast == 1)    //если == 1, то автоматическая расстановка кораблей, иначе - ручной
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            Rasstavit(m1Rab, i);
            Rasstavit(m2Rab, i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        system("cls");
        PrintArray(m1Rab, 0);
        PrintArray(m2Rab, 1);
    }

    while (tekSost != 999)
    {
        if ((chisPop1 == 20) or (chisPop2 == 20))
            break;
        if (statusGamer == 0)
        {
            switch (nomGamer)
            {
            case 1:
                nomGamer = 2;
                game(m2Rab, 2);
                break;

            case 2:
                nomGamer = 1;
                game(m1Rab, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (nomGamer)
            {
            case 1:
                game(m1Rab, 1);
                break;

            case 2:
                game(m2Rab, 2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```